# Retrieving photos around a given location using the flickr API

Tags: python, flickr

I'd like to retrieve photos around specified coordinates from flickr by using the python flickrapi wrapper to their API. My minimal example looks like this:

```
import flickrapi
api_key = "xxxx"
secret_api_key = "xxxx"
flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key, secret_api_key)

lat = 48.83417
lon = 2.221111
photo_list = flickr.photos.geo.photosForLocation(lat=lat, lon=lon, accuracy=11, format="json")
```

But, I get empty answers, i.e., photo_list looks like this:

> '{"photos":{"page":1,"pages":0,"perpage":100,"total":"0","photo":[]},"stat":"ok"}'

Any ideas about what I might be doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Turns out, retrieving photos using flickr.photos.search() works just fine.

Comment: Can you retrieve *any* photos, is your API key correct?

Answer (score 2):

try with the 'search' call instead of the 'photosForLocation', flickr.photos.geo.forLocation is very specific, and will only return photos with an exact match on the latitude and longitude, apparently

```
    import flickrapi

    api_key = "<api_key>"
    secret_api_key = "<secret_api_key>"
    flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key, secret_api_key)

    lat = 48.83417
    lon = 2.221111
    photo_list = flickr.photos.search(api_key=api_key, lat=lat, lon=lon, accuracy=11, format='parsed-json')

    print(photo_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, retrieving photos using flickr.photos.search() works just fine.